# use apache-httpClient, getResponseBodyAsStream result is not the same

Tags: java, io, httpclient

I uses httpClient3.1. I think while `length buffer.length` then a.txt  contains all of content. But it's no. Before uses `getMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream`, uses  `getMethod.getResponseBodyAsString.everything` is good. For example

```
public static void testGetResponseBodyAsStream() throws HttpException, IOException{
                /*test stackoverflow.com*/
        String uri="http://www.stackoverflow.com";
                /*uses httpClient 3.1*/
        HttpClient httpClient=new HttpClient();
        GetMethod getMethod=new GetMethod(uri);
        httpClient.executeMethod(getMethod);
                /*get result write file */
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream(new File("c:/a.txt"));
                /*buffer is Large enough*/ 
        byte[] buffer=new byte[1024*1024];
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream=new BufferedInputStream(getMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream());
                /*While  length<buffer.length then a.txt  contains all of   
                content.But it's no.  
                Before uses getMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream, uses                         
                getMethod.getResponseBodyAsString.everything is good . */     
        int length=bufferedInputStream.read(buffer,0,buffer.length);
        fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        fileOutputStream.close();
    }
```

Comment: This is not a well formed question. Please articulate a well formed question and use it in both the title and in the body.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, looks like you might not be calling some needed method:

```
String url = "https://login.yahoo.com";
String _strGetRspBody;
String _strPostRspBody;
int port = 443;
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager());
httpClient.getHostConfiguration().setHost(url, port, "https");
GetMethod authget = new GetMethod(url);
try {
    httpClient.executeMethod(authget);
} catch (IOException i) {
    logger.error(i.toString());
}
InputStream d = authget.getResponseBodyAsStream();
```

Comment: my problem is 
While  length<buffer.length then a.txt  contains all of content.But it's no.  
Before uses getMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream, uses                        getMethod.getResponseBodyAsString.everything is good .